# how do i resolve error pgadmin4 error 42p07?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-analysis, pgadmin-4

I created this table here:

```
CREATE TABLE FILM 
(Title      CHAR (180) NOT NULL,
 Year          NUMERIC (4) NOT NULL, 
 Director       CHAR (50),
 Genre      CHAR (15), 
 Country        CHAR (15),
 Distribution   CHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 ID NUMERIC (4) PRIMARY KEY
);`
```

and then i did an insert operation

```
insert into film values (‘JOJORABBIT’, ‘16gennaio’, ‘2020, ’TaikaWaititi’,‘Commedia/Drammatico’,’USA’, ‘WaltDisneyStudiosMotionPictures’, ‘1h48, ‘DD43’);
insert into film values(‘1917’, ‘23gennaio’, ‘2020’, ‘SamMendes’,’storico/drammatico’,‘RegnoUnito’, ’01DISTRIBUTION’,  ‘1h59’, ‘RE34’);
insert into film values(‘Underwater’,’30gennaio’,’2020’,’WilliamEubank’,’survival/horror’ , ‘USA’, ‘20thCenturyFox’, ’1h35’, ‘AQ67’);
```

i run it and it gave me this error: " ERROR SQL STATE 42P07, the relation "Film" already exists", how can i fix it?

thank you

Comment: See update to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see that happening is that you submitted the `CREATE TABLE` statement twice. Verify that `film` is in the database, then just run the ``` INSERT``. You should look to see if there is more then one version of ```film``` in the database. If the table name was quoted it could be in there with various spelling cases.